# Data flow in React: parent-child-parent, or parent-child?

Tags: reactjs

Given the following code, I'm wondering who is rendering the actual message. Since the flow is supposed to go from parent component, here ScreenOne, to child component, Heading, is it then that parent component sends down the message to Heading who returns the html element to the parent, and parent then renders it the actual message as the final stop? So in essence, it's going from parent to child, and back to parent?

```
// Parent 
export default class ScreenOne extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
     <View>
         <Heading message={'Custom Heading for Screen One'}/>
     </View>
    )
  }
}

// Child component
export default class Heading extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.props.message}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
Heading.propTypes = {
  message: PropTypes.string
}
Heading.defaultProps = {
  message: 'Heading One'
}
```

Comment: It might help to remember that JSX, in the words of the Docs, 'is just syntactic sugar for calling React.createElement(component, props, ...children). So, anything you can do with JSX can also be done with just plain JavaScript' [React Without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

Comment: Very helpful. Just one thing, this <View> and <Text> are just in React Native, right? I've looked them up but can't find refs to them outside of React Native /React 360 docs.

Comment: Yes, `View` is a component defined within React Native and 'maps directly to the native view equivalent on whatever platform React Native is running on' per the docs. [View](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view). You can look at it's implementation in the repository: [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/View/View.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React uses a [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) to render components. When the `<ScreenOne>` is rendered and React sees a `<Heading>` tag, it creates an instance of the `Heading` class and passes down the props. When that component is rendered and mounted into the DOM, React updates its children to look like the structure returned by `render`.